# Calling JavaScript from UIViewController

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I know we can call Java script from `UIWebView` using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` but can I call Java Script from any other place other than a view controller?

I am displaying a `UIPopover` from a WebView I want to call js code from the popover to make changes in web page displayed below.

I tried calling a method in webview from popover's viewcontroller to call js, the methord is called but nothing happened

ViewController in popover

```
webView =[WebViewController alloc]init];
[webView methodToCallJs];
```

WebViewController

```
-(void)methodToCallJs
{

[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"sampleFunction()"];

}
```

Is there a way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

I think so what you are looking for is something what this http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/ does